# Two divs 50% each. Make middle draggable to make bigger or smaller

Tags: jquery, html, drag, splitter

Alright everyone, is there a way to have 2 divs taking up 50% of the screen and have a bar in the middle so you can drag it and make the left 40% and the right 60% and vice versa.

I hope to be able to do this jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method which I quickly wrote, this does not use jQuery though.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Example Slider</title>
<style type="text/css">
    #bar1 {
        position: absolute;
        background: red;
        height: 250px;
        width: 400px;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    #bar2 {
        position: absolute;
        background: green;
        height: 250px;
        width: 800px;
    }

    #slider {
        position: relative;
        background: blue;
        height: 100%;
        width: 10px;
        float: right;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var down = false;
    var mouse_x;
    var interval;
    var IE = document.all?true:false

    if (!IE) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)
    document.onmousemove = get_mouse_x;

    function get_mouse_x(e) {
        if (IE)
            mouse_x = event.clientX;
        else
            mouse_x = e.pageX;
    }

    function drag() {
        interval = setInterval("update()", 1);
    }

    function release() {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }

    function update() {
        if ((mouse_x - document.getElementById('bar1').offsetLeft) >= document.getElementById('bar2').offsetWidth) {
            release();
            document.getElementById('bar1').style.width = document.getElementById('bar2').offsetWidth + "px";
        } else if (mouse_x <= document.getElementById('bar1').offsetLeft) {
            release();
            document.getElementById('bar1').style.width = document.getElementById('bar1').offsetLeft + "px";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('bar1').style.width = (mouse_x - document.getElementById('bar1').offsetLeft) + "px";
    }
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onmouseup="javascript:release();">
    <div id="bar1">
        <div id="slider" onmousedown="javascript:drag();"> </div>
    </div>

    <div id="bar2"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't recommend you use that on your website, instead learn from it or improve so that it is completely stable. But hopefully that gives you an idea on how to tackle this problem.

Also there's a bug in IE where, after sliding, it does not lose focus from the slider div. So this means that when you re-slide it, it doesn't release properly. To avoid this: after initial sliding, focus something else, and then slide again. Other then that it works fine.

Hopefully this was helpful in some way :)

Comment: This seems to work on all browsers and also I can change out some things so it uses jquery to shorten it or enhanse it; if needed.

Comment: You might want to disable selecting inside the slider div. As this is what causes IE not to register the click properly, it wasn't the focus issue which I presumed it was. Anyway glad this proved to be helpful.

Comment: Also it might be useful to add that incase you want to know the value of the slider (to use it as a input method) then you can retrieve that using:

var value = (100 * document.getElementById('bar1').offsetWidth) / document.getElementById('bar2').offsetWidth;

Answer (score 4):

I don't have a complete answer for you, but one thing that might be worth a look is the Resizable interaction from jQuery's UI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#synchronous-resize

It will largely depend on how you want the final product to work. You can probably set it up so that one DIV is resizable, and the adjacent one is just filling the gap.

Comment: This seems unrelated to the OP's question.  This resizes two divs the same way, not in complementary ways to add up to fill the same width.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is commonly referred to as a Spliter.  Judging by [the demo](http://methvin.com/splitter/vsplitter.html), this [jQuery plugin](http://methvin.com/splitter/) looks like it does exactly what you want.

Comment: Demo fails for me on Chrome for Mac, but that's understandable, since this is 8 years after this solution was posted.  Just helping others not follow the wrong trail...

Answer (score 0):

Insead of doing css percentages, I would find the width of the window, split it in half (minus bar width), and set pixel widths. this makes it easier to change when the bar is moved.

Answer (score -1):

This may be WAY overkill depending what else your application UI needs are, but ExtJS does this sort of thing very well.

One other unconventional option that should be mentioned: a frameset. Frames were the darling of the mid-90s, but they are still supported by just about every browser without much fuss.