# Splitter window in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, jquery

I have a master page.In that master page i have content place holder.Now i want that my page in that content place holder should be divided into two panes with the left pane displaying the links and when i click those the right pane display the page.I have searched splitter controls but none has helped and most of them are not free.So,kindly provide me the solution so that the performance of my website doesn't gets reduced

Comment: Is the right panel displaying pages within your site, external links or both?

Comment: The Component Art suite has a splitter component.

Comment: links of my site would be displayed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're looking for a splitter or just a column layout.  A splitter would allow the users to adjust the width of the columns.  If you're looking for a column layout then this is really a css/layout question.  But if you're actually looking for a splitter, then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376207/two-divs-50-each-make-middle-draggable-to-make-bigger-or-smaller) might be valuable to you.  My answer to that question includes a link to [this jQuery splitter plugin](http://methvin.com/splitter/) ([demo](http://methvin.com/splitter/vsplitter.html)).